# Google Apps Script: parsing strings as Date objects

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

All,

Consider the following JavaScript snippet, which takes a stringified date and creates a new `Date` object:

```js
var str = '2016-02-01';
var d = new Date(str);
console.log(d);
```

Running the above returns, for example, `Mon Feb 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`.

However, running the equivalent code as a Google Apps Script function does not yield the same result:

```js
function strToDateTest() {
   var str = '2016-02-01';
   var d = new Date(str);
   Logger.log(d);
}
```

In this case, the output is `Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970`.

I assume, given the differing log outputs, Google Apps Script is using its own implementation of `Date` and not [the native JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Could someone shed some light on this, and advise how best to parse date values in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Allowing implementations to parse date strings is very well known to be inconsistent across implementations, as a consequence it is strongly recommended against. Far better to manually parse date strings, a library can help or a simple function if you only have one format to deal with.

Comment: I think you mean [*built–in*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-overview) Date object (i.e. the one provided by the implementation), not *native* (which is no longer defined in the language specification). So if Google Apps Script provides a Date object, then that is the built–in (your "native") Date object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form me Google Apps Script is not running the last ECMAScript version ([doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)). So for what I could [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) this is not implemented in this version. If you decorate your string with "THH:mm:ss.sssZ" it should work:

```
function strToDateTest() {
   var str = '2016-02-01';
   str +='T00:00:00.000Z';
   var d = new Date(str);
   Logger.log(d);
}
```

Comment: According to the linked documentation, the built–in Date in Google Apps Script is based on ECMAScript ed 3, so you should not rely on it to parse **any** date string since that version of the standard does not specify any supported formats. Far better to manually parse strings with a simple function or library.