# Date.parse returns NaN in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

In Apps script, if I use:

```
function test(){
  var parsedReminderDay = Date.parse("18-Sep-2016");
  Logger.log(parsedReminderDay)
}
```

The Apps script log returns 'NaN' for me:

[image]

However, testing this with pure JS, I get the expected '1474153200000' returned:

https://jsfiddle.net/zkfxdqg4/

Why? Is Apps script bugged, or is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Not  a valid date string. Returns `NaN` in Firefox also. You will have to parse that string yourself to pass to Date object

Comment: I don't understand why JSFiddle returns the correct one then? Surely it should all fail consistently. >.<

Comment: but you are probably looking at the fiddle in chrome...I opened it in firefox and it doesn't work there but does in chrome. You have a non standard string format as per date object specs

Comment: ......That makes much more sense. If I'd had my coffee this morning, I would possibly have thought of that I hope. Feel free to add this as an actual answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Do not parse strings with Date.pares or the Date constructor (they are equivalent for parsing). Always manually parse strings. A bespoke function is a couple of lines, or use a library if you must.

Comment: @HDCerberus—it does not "fail consistently" because parsing of Date strings by ECMAScript implementations is almost entirely implementation dependent. Hence the strong recommendation to not use the built–in Date parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Google Apps Script do not run the las ECMA Script implementation (doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)). So for what I could [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) this is not implemented in this version.
Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119188/google-apps-script-parsing-strings-as-date-objects/39119717#39119717)

Comment: It would not matter if Google Apps Script was consistent with the latest ECMAScript verison, it is not required to correctly parse any string other than a limited subset of ISO 8601.